# Novel about an immortal man exposed by world government relates his life through history

Tags: story-identification, novel, immortality

I read the book from my local library in the early- to mid- seventies. It was hardcover (library bound) and the dust jacket had a printed burlap or canvas background. The back flap mentioned that the author's name was a pseudonym. The book had lots of conversation, anecdotes and opinions with little to no 'action'.  I came away with impression that the author wasn't a professional writer, but rather more like a history professor with an academic reputation to protect.

It begins shortly after the formation of a world government, and the President of Earth is presiding over the trial of Earth's only immortal man, for the crime of withholding the secret of immortality. Much of the book is taken up by his narration of stories of his life, from his birth in prehistoric times to the present. This could almost be the backstory of 'The Man From Earth', but IIRC he was never a famous person.

One anecdote I remember is what he called 'Pavlov's Other Experiment', with the supposed discoveries by the scientist after the surprising results of the 1924 Leningrad flood. The novelist added a vitamin deficiency factor that became an important plot point. There was also a story I recall as being very amusing about a British military steamship in Egypt before or during the occupation in the eighteen hundreds.

And finally, as a major plotline (such as it is), everybody is taught the simple trick to become immortal. When dead people are cloned and become 99.99% similar, their soul and memories are reunited with their bodies and they are taught immortality; time-traveling robots collect DNA from everyone who has ever lived and they become immortal as well.

This is not Bixby's "A Man From Earth", Anderson's "Boat of a Million Years", Heinlein's Lazarus Long, Borges' "The Immortal", Zelanzny's "This Immortal". The main character was not a time traveler or the Wandering Jew. It is possible I'm getting the similarity thing confused with van Vogt's Null-A, but there was something like that.

The immortal man was likely 6000-8000 years old, and the time of the novel in a future not far from now. His prehistoric tribal roots being near the invention of agriculture? (maybe)

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/wi3hk/tomtbook_scifi_immortal_man_exposed_by_world/ - Obviously

Comment: I'm sorry. @Richard, what is obvious?

Comment: Thanks. There was a second reddit thread as well, but I tried to mention the top guesses above. http://www.reddit.com/r/printSF/comments/va9dz/help_me_find_a_book_yes_another_one_of_these/

Comment: Always worth mentioning what you've tried before so you can eliminate the obvious.

Comment: Have there been any updates on this on other sites?

Comment: @GorchestopherH Nothing yet. I will update here if I get the answer.

Comment: The description you've given of the condition of the "book" in question actually sounds like you've found a single bound copy of a serial of some sort, it might be worth checking back catalogs from the like of _Strange Tales_ and _Omni_ for particular parts that stand out to you. But given that the title "Pavlov's Other Experiment" returns zero useful hits anywhere I can think of you may be out of luck I'm afraid.

Comment: @Ash, no, the book was new and a complete novel, Perhaps I mis-capitalized 'other experiment', it was just how the character referred to it. I'm still hoping someone like yourself will recognize it or discover it.

Comment: @ImaginaryEvents Elements of it do sound hauntingly familiar, but then _Time Enough for Love_ and _This Immortal_ are a couple of my favourites so it's probably just that.

Comment: The part about the protagonist being thousands of years old eliminates the novel *Operation Longlife* by E. Hoffmann Price. Doc Brandon, an obvious knockoff of the pulp hero Doc Savage, was less than two centuries old when the government realized he'd somehow stumbled across a method of keeping himself young and fit, indefinitely, and they very much wanted to persuade or coerce him to share his secrets.

Answer (score -4):

Are you looking for the Lazarus Long books?  There are several... my favorite is "Time Enough for Love".  In one of the LL stories (I think it is TEFL), I believe that he is on trial for "hiding" the "secret" to immortality, which is not so much a secret as it is an inherent part of his DNA, making him not immortal but incredibly long-lived, which is somewhat inheritable by his descendants.  He escapes earth to later return and find that humanity found the "secret" to rejuvenation.  Rejuvenation makes other extremely long-lived, but essentially makes him (with his improved DNA) immortal... funny that.

Comment: Did you see where the OP wrote "This is not ... Heinlein's Lazarus Long? (Second paragraph from the bottom.)